# What is the notation of 'a single term in the DFT'

Tags: notation, terminology, fourier-series

I have a notation/terminology question: I am writing a paper in not-quite-my-area and can't figure out the right way to phrase/notate the following:

I have a discrete function $p[x]$, of which I can assume harmonic behaviour, so the function can be substituted by a single term of its Fourier series: $p[x] \rightarrow e^{j x X}$. I am trying to come up with a notation for this, or to find the conventional notation for this. I know that this is **not** the one:

$$\mathcal{F}_x \{ p[x] \} $$

as that commonly represent the whole Fourier Transform. So I am trying to come up with an operator (say $Q$) of which:

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Q\{ p[x] \} &= e^{jxX}\\
Q\{ p[x - 3] \} &= e^{-3jxX}\\
Q \{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} p[x] \} &\approx e^{jxX} - e^{-jxX}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$

et cetera. And I'd like to know if this operator has a name. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  When you say "the function can be substituted by a single term of its Fourier series" do you mean to say that the function is equal to a complex exponential?  Or do you mean that your original function is a delta function and so the fourier transform is a complex exponential?  Or do you mean something else entirely?  Also, what do you mean by "harmonic behavior"?

Comment: No, $p[x]$ is not necessarily a delta function, that's the tricky bit, and the reason I can't use an $=$ sign. The question derives from stability analysis: it is enough to show stability for one term of the DFT, because if that is stable, all the other terms are stable too. Hence, it would be completely unnecessary to use the entire Fourier domain.

Comment: If $p$ is a function, then $\widehat p(n) \exp(in\xi)$ is a common way to write the $n$th term of its Fourier series.

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase it in terms of [Z-transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform), but I think that's overkill.  Let's use $n$ for the independent variable, then you have that $p[n]=e^{jnX}$ for some value of $X$.  This says that the sequence is periodic with a particular form.  You don't need an operator with properties you mention, they are immediate consequences of the definition of $p[n]$.  If you generalize to Fourier series with more terms, the DFT or z-transform notations are your best bet.

Just say "assume $p$ is a sequence with the form....then it follows that these properties hold..." and continue on writing the paper.

Answer (score 0):

The following book is the classic source for signal processing community:

Discrete-Time Signal Processing (2nd Edition) (Prentice-Hall Signal Processing Series) (10 January 1999), pp. 775-802 by Alan V. Oppenheim, Ronald W. Schafer, John R. Buck

Around the page 561, where the authors introduce Discrete Fourier Transform, they introduce the following notation:

> $$
> x[n]\mathop{\longleftrightarrow}^{\mathcal{DFT}} X[k].
> $$

I cannot remember any operator like notation for DFT but you may come up with something like:

> $$
> \mathcal{DFT}\left\{x[n]\right\} = X[k].
> $$

Comment: But the whole Fourier transform is exactly what I do not want, since this gives an infinite series, of which I only need a single term.

Comment: But if you look at the reference you will see that it is not the whole Fourier Transform but rather Discrete Fourier Transform which is finite. I might have misunderstood the question but you can look here too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform